# "Unpublish content" doesn't work

Tags: rules

I have a content type 'company' which has a field: field-paid. This field is a integer list who only has 1 option: 'yes'

This is my export of my rule:

```
{ "rules_testv2" : {
"LABEL" : "Depublish when not paid",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"WEIGHT" : "1",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "rules_i18n", "rules_scheduler" ],
"ON" : { "node_update" : [] },
"IF" : [
  { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "node:type" ], "value" : "company" } },
  { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "node:field-lid-" ], "value" : "1" } },
  { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_paid" } },
  { "data_is_empty" : { "data" : [ "node:field-paid" ] } }
],
"DO" : [
  { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Testing" } },
  { "schedule" : {
      "component" : "rules_delete_company",
      "date" : 1508823060,
      "identifier" : "Unpublish node [node:nid]",
      "param_node" : [ "node" ]
    }
  }
]
  }
}
```

Now I've tried like this (without my component) but still not working:

```
 { "rules_testv2" : {
"LABEL" : "Depublish when not paid",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"WEIGHT" : "1",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
"ON" : { "node_update" : [] },
"IF" : [
  { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "node:type" ], "value" : "company" } },
  { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "node:field-lid-" ], "value" : "1" } },
  { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_paid" } },
  { "data_is_empty" : { "data" : [ "node:field-paid" ] } }
],
"DO" : [ { "node_unpublish" : { "node" : [ "node" ] } } ]
  }
}
```

It unpublish all my nodes... But I have 2 nodes (for testing) that has value in 'field-paid' (checkbox) so normally those 2 nodes has to remain published...

Comment: please include an export of your rule, so that somebody who wants to recreate your scenario can do so also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple possibilities that may be causing your issue. So below is 1 hint for each of them to verify ...

#### Hint 1:

To simplify your debugging, just for temporary unit testing, add a Rules Action (as the very first Rules Action) to "Show a message on a site", e.g to say 'Bingo, let the Rules party begin (we did find a combination of Rules Conditions to continue building on)'. This is much easier to do debugging then the ultimate set of Rules Actions you want to get to work.

#### Hint 2:

Not sure if it is "the" reason why your rule doesn't work, but try to add an extra Rules Condition like ""entity has field" (for your `field-paid` field). And make sure this is added before any other Rules Condition in which you want to check the value of that field. The bets are open ...

#### Hint 3:

As per your question, your `field-paid` field can only have value "yes" (or no value at all I assume). So replace your last Rules Condition (= "not empty") by a "data comparison" (to check if the value is NOT "yes", and note the NOT-negation here). Also note that after you applied hint 1, the "entity has field" will contradict your "not empty" (so both Rules Conditions can never be true together, so your Rules Conditions would never be executed).

Comment: I've tried with 'entity has field' but still not working correctly.  My export you can find in my question.

Comment: Hi Pierre. Yes, 'field-lid-' is correct. I've now removed the first 2 rules, so now I have Entity has field ('field-paid') and Data value is empty Parameter: Data to check: [node:field-paid]. Now when I run cron all the nodes stays published so my rule is not working at all. I've enable my debugging but cannot find this log :-/.

Comment: @user2848993 your turn again, check "hint 3" (the rest is rather a reprhasing of what was there before). And please try to use that temporary bingo-trick (to simplify debugging, first your Rules Conditions must be correct before your ultimate Rules Actions you want to get to work, that's for afterwards). Let me know the results, ok? PS: I disagree this question was put on hold, it is NOT "unclear what you're asking", at least not to me. So you may want to flag your own question to get it reopened (I already voted to reopen it).

Comment: Thank you very much Pierre. Ok, I'm a step further now, when I changed my 'not empty' into 'data comparison' it works when I "edit" and "save" the node manually, I think this is because the "After updating existing content".  How could I get it done that this is now running via cron?

Comment: @steven (you changed user name ...?!?!) great, making progress ... you now have a set of Rules Conditions "to let the Rules Party begin" (cfr hint 1). Proposal: consider this answer as "enough to resolve your issue with your Rules Conditions" and mark my answer as accepted. Then create a new question (with a link to this one), in which you post an export of your rule that works manually, and add a (new) question there like "how to get this running via cron". This will also avoid "this" question becomes a chameleon question (which would invalidate my current answer). Agree?